# How to code jquery in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following controller and view. I am trying to learn jquery in codeigniter.

The code does not work. So I am hoping someone spot out what I am doing wrong and correct me.

Thanks in advance.

```
class PhpJqueryBook extends Controller
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::Controller(); }

public function index()
{
...    }

function dynamic_select_boxes(){

    $this->load->view('dynamic_select_boxes');

}

function get_cities(){

    switch(@$_POST['country']){
        case 'ie': // { ireland
            $cities=array('Cork', 'Dublin', 'Galway', 'Limerick',
              'Waterford');
        break;
        // }
        case 'uk': // { United Kingdom
            $cities=array('Bath', 'Birmingham', 'Bradford',
                'Brighton &amp; Hove', 'Bristol',
                'Cambridge', 'Canterbury', 'Carlisle',
                'Chester', 'Chichester', 'Coventry',
                'Derby', 'Durham', 'Ely', 'Exeter',
                'Gloucester', 'Hereford', 'Kingston upon Hull',
                /* and on and on! */
                'Newport', 'St David\'s', 'Swansea');
        break;
        // }
        default: // { else
            $cities=false;
        // }
    }
    if(!$cities)echo 'please choose a country first';
    else echo '<select name="city"><option>'.join('</option>  <option>',$cities).'</select>';
}
}
```

views/dynamic_select_boxes.php

```
<?php $this->load->view('inc/header')?>

<form>
<table>
<tr><th>Country</th><td>
<select name="country" id="country">
<option value=""> -- please choose -- </option>
<option value="ie">Ireland</option>
<option value="uk">Great Britain</option>
</select>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Cities</th>
<td id="cities">please choose a country first</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php $this->load->view('inc/footer')?>
```

And this produces the following html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <base href="http://127.0.0.1/ci_jquery/">
</head>
<body>

<form>
<table>
    <tr><th>Country</th><td>
    <select name="country" id="country">
    <option value=""> -- please choose -- </option>
    <option value="ie">Ireland</option>
    <option value="uk">Great Britain</option>
    </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Cities</th>
    <td id="cities">please choose a country first</td>
</tr>
    </table>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(setup_country_change);
        function setup_country_change(){
            $('#country').change(update_cities);
        }
        function update_cities(){
            var country=$('#country').attr('value');
            $.get('phpjquerybook/get_cities/'+country, show_cities);
        }
        function show_cities(res){
            $('#cities').html(res);
        }       
        </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the third parameter in a method of a controller you can easily use the parameters of the method to get these, or the uri class to get the segments. In the first case you would use

```
function get_cities($country = null){

    switch($country){

    ....
```

see codeigniter userguide for [passing uri parameters to controllers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri)  and [uri library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the way you are attempting to identify the city.  You are sending a GET request via Ajax with Jquery on this line:

```
$.get('phpjquerybook/get_cities/'+country, show_cities);
```

However, in your `get_cities()` function, you are checking `$_POST` for the requested country.  `$_POST` will be empty if you are sending a GET request.

The best thing to do here would be to change this line:

```
switch(@$_POST['country'])
```

to

```
switch($_GET['country'])
```

An alternate solution would be to modify your JQuery call to be a `$.post()` instead.

I highly recommend you don't use the `@` operator while developing either, unless you really need it for specific functionality.  You would have noticed this if you hadn't suppressed the error about `$_POST['country']` not being set.  It is better practice to fix your errors than suppress them.

Comment: This is wrong for several reasons: 1. see my answer and 2. GET parameters are filtered by the CI input class, see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html